# Implementing Bootstrap Toggle Switch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement toggle switches from http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/.

gem 'rails-bootstrap-toggle-buttons'

> > bundle

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-toggle-buttons
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

and

```
 *= require bootstrap-toggle-buttons
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

view:

```
<%= f.check_box :email_notifications, :'data-toggle'=>"toggle" %>
```

Is just giving me a plain checkbox. Any clues on why this would not be working?

Answer (score 1):

First: you wanted to have the toggle switches from http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/ but from what I see the `rails-bootstrap-toggle-buttons` gem seems to contain the toggle switches from http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/. This could have been your issue since the latter does not support initialization via the HTML `data-toggle` attribute.

Since I also wanted to use the former library due to performance issues with the latter and did not find a gem which shipped it through the asset pipeline I created one: `bootstrap-toggle-rails`. You can find the documentation in the [README](https://github.com/rkallensee/bootstrap-toggle-rails/blob/master/README.md).

But: the `data-toggle` initialization method also didn't work for me in combination with Turbolinks, but you can make it work by just initializing it manually with JavaScript and skip the `data-toggle` attribute and e.g. add a `toggle` class:

```
$(document).on('ready page:change', function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"].toggle').bootstrapToggle(); // assumes the checkboxes have the class "toggle"
});
```

Note the `page:change` event, which is fired by Turbolinks, in addition to the `ready` event.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using >Rails 4 and >Ruby 1.9

```
<%= f.check_box :email_notifications, :data => { :toggle => 'toggle' } %>
```

Make sure that your HTML is being generated correctly.

```
<!-- Something like this -->
<input type="checkbox" name="email_notifications" data-toggle="toggle">
```

Then check the JavaScript console to make sure there are no errors.

Comment: Changed the erb code, double checked the html generated: <input data-toggle="toggle" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="shop[email_notifications]" id="shop_email_notifications"> .. No JS errors.. thoughts?

Comment: Hmm the only other thing I noticed was that the gem you're using hasn't updated the bootstrap toggle assets in over 3 years. You might want to try manually including the bootstrap toggle assets instead of using the gem.

Comment: looks like it's a turbolinks issue.. removed turbo links and it works fine.,

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to add style, simple do like:

```
<%= f.check_box :subscribed_to_news, data: { toggle: 'toggle', style: 'ios' } %>
```