# Javascript syntax in a rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am trying to implement Bootstrap Toggle in my rails app to show/hide a div based in the selection of a checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" unchecked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Scheduling" data-off="Simple Mode" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="default" class="bstoggle" id="bstoggle">

<div id="scheduling_options" style="display: none">
  Configure Scheduling
</div>
```

I have added the following code to the relevant .coffee file and loaded that in application.js as follows:

```
$(document).ready ->
   $(".bstoggle").bootstrapToggle()

   $(".bstoggle").change ->
     $("#scheduling_options").toggle(!this.checked)
```

The checkbox is appearing as a toggle but the div is not being displayed when I toggle the checkbox.

I'm sure it's apparent but I am very new and unfamiliar with javascript.

Comment: From my murky knowledge: `.bstoggle` is a class... which means it can be put on more than one html element - and thus jquery expects you'll get an array-full of returned elements that you have to use `each` to iterate through, toggling them all. If you want one, you can just use the id eg: `#bstoggle`

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code (both in straight html and in a rails app), and the div (and text 'Configure Scheduling') is being shown when I click the toggle (at least the first time), so it looks like it is something to do with your environment / dependencies.  Bstoggle is a js add in (http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/), and you may have overlooked including this, you can do this by including  `<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>`  in your viewfile, or perhaps download the minified js and include it from the local source.  That's without the gem (see [Implementing Bootstrap Toggle Switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510159/implementing-bootstrap-toggle-switch)).